# How do i make my site responsive? why is this wrong?

Tags: css

I coded my first site the other day and coded it to look good on desktops.
I am now trying to make it responsive and so targetting the mobile resolution first.

I did this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:375px){
```

To try and only change things when it is on a mobile however this has changed m desktop too. Why is this?
thanks

Comment: min-width: 375px means when your screen width is bigger than 375px. change it to max-width:375px.

Comment: @George thanks i will give it a go